# MQTT publish two values to a Topic

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mqtt, arduino-ide

Currently my sketch publishes one sensor value per topic. I will like to publish two messages one topic like [this](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/mqtt-publish-divided-values-to-same-topic/2236/3)

**arduino**

```
void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

 int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int t = DHT.temperature;
  int h = DHT.humidity;

  char buffer[10];
  dtostrf(t,0, 0, buffer);
  client.publish("Sensor/Temperature", buffer);
  Serial.println(buffer);
  dtostrf(h,0, 0, buffer);
  client.publish("Sensor/Humidity",buffer);
  delay(1000);
}
```

I will like this sketch to store in my MongoDB. Currently I only accepts one topic and one message.

**server.JS**

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        var messageObject = {
            topic: topic,
            message: message.toString(),
            Time:  new Date()
        };

        collection.insert(messageObject, function(error, result) {
            if(error != null) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I push two sensor values to a single topic from my Arduino?

Thanks for your anticipated effort.

Comment: There doesn't seam to be a question or a description of a problem here

Comment: @hardillb Updated post

Comment: What is wrong with the code example you have provided?

Comment: I will like to achieve that. Now my arduino only publishes one sensor data per topic. I will like to publish temperature and humidity in one topic. Like `{topic: sensor, temperature: 20, humidity:23}`

Comment: Have you tried using ArduinoJson to generate the JSON on the Arduino? Then publish that over MQTT? https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very suitable solution to this. Hopefully it helps someone.

```
void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

 int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int t = DHT.temperature;
  int h = DHT.humidity;
  snprintf (msg, 75, "temperature %d humidity  %d ledStatus %s", t,h,ledStatus);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
    delay(6000);
}
```